# access an element inside ng-repeat when dynamic html loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to access an DOM element inside a dymanic loaded HTML with http get request. The code that I am using inside controller is

```
$http.get("/ProjectManager/Edit?id=" + requestId).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        data = data.trim();
        var newDirective = angular.element(data);
        angular.element(document.getElementById("editDiv")).html(newDirective);
        $compile(newDirective)($scope);
        var resources = angular.element(document.getElementById("projectResources")).val();
            for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
                var resourceData = new ProjectResourcesModel(resources[i].ResourceID, resources[i].ProjectResourceID, resources[i].Employee, resources[i].IsApprover, resources[i].StartDate,
                    resources[i].EndDate)
                $scope.resource.push(resourceData);
                //$scope.$apply();
                var id = "startDate" + resources[i].ResourceID;
                angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: resources[i].StartDate,
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                })
            }
    })
```

I am trying to access a element with particular id that is present in  my array element.

View HTML inside a ng-repeat is as follows

```
 <div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class='input-group date' id='startDate{{item.ResourceID}}'>
 <span class="input-group-addon">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
 </span>
 <input ng-model="item.StartDate" type='text' id="txtStartDate{{item.ResourceID}}" class="form-control" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I have to attach bootstrap datetimepicker to a textbox so I want to access a div inside ng-repeat whose ID is present inside by ng-repeat array.
But when I access the item with that id inside success of get request I am not getting the element. for e.g id of div would be startDate151 after the view binding.

So I tried using $scope.$apply() with which I am able attach the datepicker to element inside ng-repeat but I started getting a console error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this or can I use some other alternative in this situation.